PanicException: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidOperation(ErrString("`list_builder` operation not supported for dtype `object`"))
I get the error on this code,
df = df.with_columns(list_title=[pl.col('title')]))

when I print df.schema, I get,
OrderedDict({'title': String, ...

the title column is of type pl.String, but for some reason polars is taking it as of type pl.Object, and the list creation is failing, I have substituted it currently like this,
df = df.with_columns(list_title=pl.col('title').map_elements(lambda x: [x]))

but is there a way to make this work without using map_elements?

The PanicException should be filed as a bug. It is not really clear what you're trying to do. Are you looking for concat_list? e.g. list_title=pl.concat_list('title')

A reproducible example of the PanicException appears to have been reported: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/17413

Try to diagnose and solve this issue step by step:

First, let's check the exact dtype of your 'title' column:

print(df['title'].dtype)

If this returns pl.Object instead of pl.String, we need to investigate why.

Let's examine the contents of the 'title' column:

print(df['title'].head())
print(df['title'].value_counts().head())

This will show us the first few values and the most common values in the column.
